# How to transfer states among components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React JS, I want to create a ToDo list app. I have `App.js` which is the main page and so I have created `MainBlock` component for `App.js` page which holds left and right side of my layout and in right side property it loads `Form` component which has `input` and `button` and saves input values to an array in `state` and in left side it loads `List` component which has a property named `allTasks` which prints all tasks.
My problem is how can I transfer `allTasks` state from Form Component to `App.js` to pass it to `List` component property?
In App.js :

```
<MainBlock
left={  
    <List allTasks={['خرید از فروشگاه', 'تعویض دستگیره درب منزل']} />} 
right={
    <Form />
} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by storing the tasks as state in the App component, and have Form pass up the state through a callback prop. This concept is called "lifting state up". Here's a guide about it: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

```
<MainBlock
  left={
    <List allTasks={this.state.allTasks} />
  }
  right={ 
    <Form onSubmit={allTasks => this.setState({ allTasks })} />
  }
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did this but when I click on button in the form it refreshes the page.

Comment: You need to do event.preventDefault() in your form's onSubmit handler. In the future, if you want to ask something unrelated to the original question, make a new question.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I know about it but I mean how to use event,preventDefault in ReactJS side by side the function above you wrote? If you edit for me It is great help. Again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let tasks be a state of the MainBlock component. Pass this state down to the List component.
2. Let the Form component expose a callback property (maybe `onTaskCreated`) which is invoked when user complete creating a new task.
3. Let MainBlock intercept `onTaskCreated` callbacks and update it's internal state with the new task, which causes it to re-render and thus passing down the new task list to the List component.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve two way binding here. Unfortunately, React is a library that doesn't support two way binding by default. 
You can only pass in the values from Parent to Child to Sub-Child. However, the reverse is not true.
In this case, you are trying to load props from `Form` to `App` that is from Child to Parent which is not possible.

You should make use of state containers such as Redux that overcomes this limitation by making the state of one component available to the other component.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your tasks in the state of the MainBlock component and pass functions to update the state by your form. Also, pass the state (tasks) of MainBlock to your List component. Updating your tasks to MainBlock will automatically pass the tasks to List. Later you could use a state management library like MobX and Redux.

Answer (score 0):

It can be confusing passing data between components. Libraries like redux were created to make this "easier", but it can be done with simple React. To pass state information to children, you pass it into their props. To send data the other direction, you pass (from parent to child) a handler function that is called from the child and can affect the state of the parent (or be passed to it's parent) as needed.

I wrote a [sample](https://codepen.io/kevinsmithwebdev/pen/RgXbzP) pen to help people wrap their heads around this. Hopefully it helps.

Something like:

```
<Child1 handleAdd={this.handleAdd.bind(this)} 
    handleSubtract={this.handleSubtract.bind(this)} 
/>
```

calls in the parent and and is accessed in the child as:

```
<Button onClick={this.onAdd.bind(this)}>
    add
</Button>&nbsp;
<Button onClick={this.props.handleSubtract.bind(this)}>
    subtract
</Button>
```

Then there is a function in the parent called *handleAdd* that can affect the parent state.